# how to append a list to the generator?

Tags: python, generator

I have list of countries and regions given in properties file and the generator is created from it like this.

```
lvls = {"Belgium": "EUR", "GER": "EUR"}
data_gen = ((f'{idx}', f'{lvl}') for idx, lvl in lvls.items())
```

The output of generator `list(data_gen)` is

```
[('Belgium', 'EUR'), 
('Germany', 'EUR'),
....]
```

I take each key of `lvls` which is country and fetch its country from database and now I want to append it to the generator such as output should be

```
[('Brussel','Belgium', 'EUR'),('Gent','Belgium', 'EUR'),('Bruge','Belgium', 'EUR')]
```

but not sure how to append it to the generator with repeating existing values of country and region.

Thus the final generator would be

```
[('Brussel','Belgium', 'EUR'),('Gent','Belgium', 'EUR'),('Bruge','Belgium', 'EUR'),  
( 'Berlin','Germany', 'EUR'),( 'Frankfurt','Germany', 'EUR')
....]
```

Comment: Since generator is a one shot iterator, I don't think you can append to a specific value multiple times. I propose a solution to make it a list first by calling ```list``` and then iterate through it.

Comment: can I do this while creating a generator?

Comment: What type is the result of your database query? is it something like this `{"Belgium":["Brussels", "Gent", "Bruge"], "Germany":["Berlin", "Frankfurt"]}`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the output from the database would be like:

```
cities = [('Brussel', 'Belgium'), ('Gent', 'Belgium'), ('Frankfurt', 'Germany')]
```

Then you could just use the dict that you already have like this:

```
((city, country, lvls[country]) for city, country in cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database query returns output in this manner: `database = {"Belgium":["Brussels", "Gent", "Bruge"], "Germany":["Berlin", "Frankfurt"]}`. You can achieve your purpose using list comprehension:

```
lvls = {"Belgium": "EUR", "Germany": "EUR"}
database = {"Belgium":["Brussels", "Gent", "Bruge"], "Germany":["Berlin", "Frankfurt"]}
one = [(y,x,lvls[x]) for x,sub in database.items() for y in sub]
print(one)
```

> Output

```
[('Brussels', 'Belgium', 'EUR'), ('Gent', 'Belgium', 'EUR'), ('Bruge', 'Belgium', 'EUR'), ('Berlin', 'Germany', 'EUR'), ('Frankfurt', 'Germany', 'EUR')]
```